# Should HMAC key be changed regularly? Should it be kept secret at all times?

Tags: encryption, hmac

I am doing an HMAC of some cipher-text, IV and encryption algorithm. Right now I am using a hard-coded key that is known to both sender and receiver. I was wondering if the key should be changed once in a while? If it does, how would I synchronize the keys with the receiver? Is sending the HMAC key in plain-text a very bad idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to change the HMAC key unless you believe it has been compromised (or for some other reason, you wish for messages authenticated under the old key to no longer be considered valid).  Assuming you use a reasonable hash function, signing "too many" messages with the same key does not compromise the key.

All of the security of HMAC comes from the HMAC key being kept secret, so sending it in plaintext would almost certainly defeat the whole purpose of using HMAC rather than just a public, unkeyed hash.  If you need to be able to change keys, you may want to rely on asymmetric (public key) cryptography instead, although you haven't stated enough about your application for a more specific recommendation to be possible.

Comment: The application consist of passing data: server1-client1-server2. Where client1, can not be trusted and is expected to tamper with data if it's possible to do so. Hence the payload is encrypted by server1 and HMAC is taken and appended to control the integrity of the package, making sure that the client1 did not replace the ciphertext with client2's one. The HMAC is extracted from ciphertext, iv and unique client1 identifier, this way server2 can quickly check if the payload came from server1 and if it was intended to go via client1. The encryption is AES256-CBC.